# How to skip passing type in implementing c# non-generic interface generic property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using a '[Clean Architecture](https://github.com/JasonGT/CleanArchitecture)' solution template, and I believe it's very promising, however, I'm facing a problem in separating the `ApplicationUser` class derived from `IdentityUser` since they are both parts of the infrastructure layer and I've got a dependency on it on the core layer 'Domain' when defining an Account Entity referencing `ApplicationUser`, so as I'm doing the references in one-way from inside to outside I can't use it down there, so I passed a generic type but I still can't implement the `ApplicationDbContext` in the infrastructure, any thoughts?

Account.cs

```
using MacSys.Domain.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MacSys.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Account<T> : LocaleEntityBase
    {
        public Account()
        {
            ApplicationUsers = new List<T>();
        }
        public City City { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<T> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

IApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using MacSys.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App.Application.Common.Interfaces
{
    public interface IApplicationDbContext
    {
        DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
        DbSet<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }
        DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
        DbSet<Account<??>> Accounts { get; set; }

        Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using App.Application.Common.Interfaces;
using App.Domain.Entities;
using App.Infrastructure.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using App.Infrastructure.Identity.ApplicationGroups;

namespace App.Infrastructure.Persistence
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, 
        ApplicationRole,
        string>, IApplicationDbContext
    {
        private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
        private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;

        public ApplicationDbContext(
            DbContextOptions options,
            ICurrentUserService currentUserService,
            IDateTime dateTime) : base(options)
        {
            _currentUserService = currentUserService;
            _dateTime = dateTime;
        }

        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Account<ApplicationUser>> Accounts { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I'm having the error in the ApplicationDbContext class implementation since I can't find a relation between both properties without making dual references between projects.

Comment: do you really think that this is a good approach? if I may ask what other classes are using IApplicationDbContext interface?

Comment: I don't know what approach exactly you're wondering about, anyway I'm using `IApplicationDbContext` heavily in the application of course.

Comment: Could you explain what problem you are facing in a way that does not require me to actually learn about this “Clean Architecture” thing first? Is it that you want to separate your *user* entity from the ApplicationIdentity entity?

Comment: Well, Let's say I'm having 3 projects in one solution (domain, application, and infrastructure), in the domain I describe the domain model without any business, in the application I handle the business logic, and in infrastructure, I use SQL, Identity
When I try to implement application's `IApplicationDbContext` in the infrastructure, one of the domain models 'Accounts', have a dependency on `IdentityUser` class in the infrastructure, I can't reference it in the domain to avoid circular dependency, How to pass such dynamic value across layers without converting to `IApplicationDbContext<T>` ?

Answer (score 0):

One common approach to separating your domain from the framework would be by not coupling them at all. You actually do not have to have all your entities in the same database context, and you do not need to make your account entity inherit from `ApplicationUser` either.

Instead, what you can do is completely separate these two concerns: Use the standard `IdentityDbContext` with its `IdentityUser` as the primary user identity for *authentication and authorization*. But maintain a separate `Account` entity for your domain. You can even share the same user id to get a one-to-one mapping. If you then put the `Account` and the rest of the domain model into its own database context, then your domain entities are completely separate from the auth framework layer of your application.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer and sorry for my late reply, but in your solution could you describe how it's possible to create a relation between my `auth user` and `accounts`, since we have a relation, and won't be broken, each account should have a number of auth users.
I may think that you mean to just make a reference of `AccountId` in the `AspNetUser` and then wherever I'd like to get account-users or vice-versa I should make double trip since - ofcourse - I don't have a navigation property!

Comment: You don’t have a navigation property but you don’t necessarily need multiple trips to the database. Usually, you would want all the necessary information about your user to be available from the user claims. So you could for example have your auth user maintain an `AccountId` in the database but also expose that through claims. So when you need to look up the current user’s account, you just need to retrieve the claim and then make a single trip to the database with that id.